# Is Digimon Tri canon?

Tags: digimon

There is a Digimon Adventure 1 picture in one of the episodes, but the public seem to have forgotten previous Digimon appearances in the real world.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Toei Animation, the original production company that put out Digimon Adventures, is definitely [advertising](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVnqtcBcsPo) it as a sequel to the original stories.

The release of Digimon Adventure Tri is supposed to be their *gift*
 to Digimon fans for the fifteen year anniversary of the ending of the original show.

You mention that it seems the public has forgotten past Digimon appearances in the world but I don't think so. After their appearance and destruction of the airport and town the news reporter states that this serves as a reminder of their destructive power.  The fact that this is a reminder proves that they've seen events like this before.

[image: Digimon Tri Screenshot: and serverd as a reminder of their menace and destructive power]